# boost::filesystem::file_size error when using a path with whitespace

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, filesize

I'm asking `boost::filesystem::file_size` for a file with path `"/tmp/test\ file.txt"`, and it reports no such file or directory when it is there.

```
Error: fs::file_size("/tmp/test\ file.txt") reported boost::filesystem::file_size: No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rturrado users 12486 Mar 15 12:01 /tmp/test file.txt
```

Are there any considerations when using paths with escaped sequences in boost::filesystem?

Comment: Escaping the space in that filename seems strange.

Comment: Does the filename really have a backslash in it, or is that only to escape the space for the shell? What is the actual code you wrote?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks guys. I didn't need the escape. The real filename should be "/tmp/test file.txt", without the quotes. And I was passing "/tmp/test\\ file.txt" as a parameter. But just passing "/tmp/test file.txt" is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closing this question, as I fixed the issue thanks to Mat and ymett comments.

`boost::filesystem::file_size("/tmp/test file.txt")` works just fine. You don't need any escaping.